# Kubuntu 20.10 - how to change audio balance? (left/right)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, kde

i have up-to-date Kubuntu 20.10, and i'm looking for 5 minutes how to change audio balance (left/right) ??
loudspeakers on my desk are not evenly set and i need to adjust balance for that one output (USB DAC).
Where to do that? i'm looking in audio options/settings for 5 minutes and i can't find it.

Comment: You could install `pavucontrol`, open it, find your device in the output tab, click on the lock to unlock the left and right channels, and then adjust. Someone may have an easier way to do that with Kubuntu (i'm not a user, I use Lubuntu) so this solution should work if nobody else has an easier way to do it without installing anything.